# How to safely delete eav_attribute table in mysql

Tags: magento

I want to delete **eav_attribute** table from Magento database.

I am getting `#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

How can i delete it safely?

Comment: Huh? Why do you want to delete that table? That's the center point of Magento. Everything will blow up if you delete that (including the universe).

Comment: @Marius I have backup of the old table, I want to re import this to my database.Will this disturb the normal functioning of Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are walking on shallow ice here.
There is a high chance that this deleting the table will break your website. There are foreign keys to that table for example from `catalog_eav_attribute` and `customer_eav_attribute`. Also all the tables that hold attribute values are linked to `eav_attribute`.
Like `catalog_product_entity_int` for example.
If you want to add or update attributes from that table you should find an other way. Like using install scripts where you use '$this->addAttribute' or `$this->updateAttribute`.